# Why redirecting to another page is not wokring in php through AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I am redirecting to another page in PHP through AJAX, but why is it not working ?
**PAGE : index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Ajax Redirection </title>
</head>

<!-- body-------------------------  -->
<body>
    <button id='btn'>press</button>

    <script>
        let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

        <!-- JAVASCRIPT----------------------  -->
        function ajax() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', './process.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest');

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                console.log('xhr.readyState = '+ xhr.readyState, ', xhr.status = '+xhr.status);   
        }
        /* Sending the request */
        xhr.send();
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click',ajax);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PAGE : process.php**

```
<?php
header("Location: " . '/');
exit;
?>
```

**OUTPUT : console.log output**

```
xhr.readyState = 2 , xhr.status = 200
xhr.readyState = 3 , xhr.status = 200
xhr.readyState = 4 , xhr.status = 200
```

Accordnig output of console.log, there is no any error in PHP-AJAX code.
But still redirecting is not working as defined in `process.php` page.
**Why ?**

Comment: `header("Location: " . '/');` ?? Why no a simple `header("Location: /");`

Comment: It probably does work, you're making an _asynchronous_ additional request to `process.php`, which gets redirected to `/`. Use your browser's DevTools/Network Tab to see the redirection happening

Comment: @kerbholz yes you're right, but please tell me why is this not redirecting to ```/``` in front-end. and how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Because it's a different request. Have you checked @FernandoUrban s answer? You need to redirect on the client-side (JS), not the server-side (PHP)

Comment: okay I got it. Thanks to be here

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect trough `AJAX` response from your `php` script because `AJAX` can only recieve `data` like **objects**, **strings** or anything avaliable to be render by `javascript`.

I mean, you can't return instructions because `AJAX` can't understand them. So, if your goal is redirect with `AJAX`, try to get some kind of response that you can read in javascript and then do something.

In your `javascript` do:

```
function ajax() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', './process.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if ( parseInt(xhr.responseText) == 1 ) {
          //here after read server response and if it's equals 1 you can redirect with javascript
          window.location.href= "somefile.php";
       }
    }
}
/* Sending the request */
xhr.send();
```

**xhr.responseText** will recieve and read your server response, and with `parseInt` function of javascript you can convert that "1" string to Integer as natural number `1`

And from your  `process.php` file:

```
<?php
   //after all your script process you need to output the number one.
   echo 1;
?>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: ........oh that's why redirecting is not working in my code. Thanks !

Comment: Note: redirection _is_ working in your code, just not where you want it to happen ;)